# Java errors with creating function

Tags: java, function

I have created a class which should create Swords, but I just get a bunch of errors...

```
package swords;

public class Sword {

public static void main(String [ ] args){

    public int numberOfSwords=0;

    public static void newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword){
        numberOfSwords++;

    }
  }
}
```

I want to, when I type `newSword(Overpowered Sword, 1000000)`, increase the int `numberOfSwords` by one, the actual creation of the sword will come later :D

But I get a lot of errors:

At `package swords;`   - The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

At `public class Sword {`   - Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

At `public static void main(String [ ] args){`   - String cannot be resolved to a type

At `public int numberOfSwords=0;`   - Illegal modifier for parameter numberOfSwords; only final is permitted

And the final error at `public static void newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword){`   - Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    - void is an invalid type for the variable newSword
    - String cannot be resolved to a type
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

I hope you can help me!

EDIT: I'm running Linux Mint, so I dont know if it could be something with my system, since I tried the given code, but get the same errors! I'm investigating now ^ ^

EDIT 2: I just ran a command which told me I didn't have a JDK installed, I think I found the problem :P I'll pay more attention to requirements in the future, sorry...

EDIT 3: Apparently I do have a JDK installed, so I dont know anymore what the problem is... Suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: I am sure you know how to write a java program , but you might have missed to note somehow that you are trying to nest another function in main()

Answer (score 2):

Try this

in Sword.Java

```
public class Sword{
    public Sword(string name, int damage){
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
        ++swordsCreated;
    }
    public string getName(){ return name; }
    public int getDamage(){ return damage; }
    
    private string name;
    private int damage;
    
    public static int getCountOfSwordsCreated(){ return countOfSwordsCreated; }
    private static int countOfSwordsCreated;
}
```

in Game.java

```
public class Game{
    public static void main(string [] args)
    {
        Sword mySword = new Sword("Overpowered Sword", 1000000);

        System.out.println(mySword.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't name variable with "_", use this.name = name!

Comment: @ThomasUhrig changed to match official style guidelines from sun. That said, there are plenty of style guidelines that suggest otherwise.

Comment: I don't know any style guide for Java that suggests "_" ;), however, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you want, something like this?

```
package swords;

public class Sword {

    public static int numberOfSwords = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newSword("Overpowered Sword", 1000000);
    }

    public static void newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword) {
        numberOfSwords++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm just experimenting with Java and want to create a function which let me `newSword(nameSword, damageSword)`, just for the heck of it xD So when i create like a textbased rpg to easily create more than one sword...

EDIT: I just tried your code, I still get the same errors, could it be something with settings or something? I'm running Eclipse on Linux Mint... Maybe that can help.

Comment: I just tried your code, I still get the same errors, could it be something with settings or something? I'm running Eclipse on Linux Mint... Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help.

```
package swords;

class Sword {
    private static int numberOfSwords = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newSword("Overpowered Sword", 100);
    }

    public static void newSword(String nameSword, int damageSword) {
        numberOfSwords++;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

It is a good practice to keep variables private and functions public. So that the public functions are the only possible way to access the variables, ensuring security.

Ensure that you save the code as Sword.java in a folder swords

Comment: I just keep getting errors, also with your code... I think it's something with my system, I'm running Linux, so maybe there is something with a path??

Comment: Try out a simple hello world program

Comment: @user2998976 - no, there's a syntax error in his code (`numberOfSwords` needs the `static` modifier).

Comment: Lol. Thanks for the heads up. Sort of forgot about that. My bad.

Comment: Well that fixed one error ^ ^ But why does it need to be static, and what does that mean?

Comment: Static methods can only access static variables

Comment: Fixed another possible error. You are calling the function, `newSword` with a long, where as the function declaration uses int.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 problems with your code:

Firstly, you are trying to pass a long value to an integer parameter of your function.

Next, numberOfSwords is declared and initialized in main() method, so it's a local variable. You need to make it global in order to access it from your newSword() method.

The following code snippet works perfectly in my NetBeans IDE 7.3. I think this is going to work for you.

Happy coding!!! :) :)

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package sword;

/**
*
* @author Jack Sparrow
*/
public class Sword {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * 
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     newSword("Overpowered Sword",1000000); 

}

public static void newSword(String nameSword, long damageSword)
    {
        int numberOfSwords = 0;
        if ((nameSword == ("Overpowered Sword")) && (damageSword == 1000000))
        {
            numberOfSwords++;
            System.out.println(numberOfSwords);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME/JDK refers to valid path. When valid java not found than it gives java.lang related errors.